# Guava cache eviction before expireAfterWrite and before max size is reached

Tags: caching, guava

I'm using Guava cache as non-loading cache in my project and set the max size and expire after write

```
CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
    .expireAfterWrite(1h)
    .maximumSize(5000)
    .recordStats()
```

I used the cache in a multi-thread environment and i'm populating the cache using some custom load method, by which i'm doing something like:

```
lock(key)
1. Check if key is present in cache
2. if not, spin up an sync cache retrieval request(it's a future) and cache the request in an internal map(if there are following requests asking for same key, i will just return the cached retrieval request)
```

After deploying the application, i noticed some weird eviction behavior:
The cache starts to evict at size around 1000 and at time around 20 minutes after the application has started.

Has anyone experienced this situation before?

Thanks!

Comment: Guava segments by the concurrencyLevel, default 4, and chooses the segment by the hash. This implies a constant/poor hash where you fill only one segment so it evicts early (5000/4=1250 max). Do your keys have a good hash/equals implementation?

Comment: fyi, the Guava team not [recommends](https://guava.dev/releases/32.1.2-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html) using Caffeine, which includes an [AsyncCache](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.github.ben-manes.caffeine/caffeine/latest/com.github.benmanes.caffeine/com/github/benmanes/caffeine/cache/AsyncCache.html). That might simplify your logic by not using a secondary map for request futures.